# how to position camera in XNA 10 units away but not from behind?

Tags: c#, object, xna, camera, position

I want the camera to be for example 10 units away from an object, but not behind it.
But not like this, because the camera always will be behind the object:

```
cameraPosition = objectPosition + object.Backwards * 10;
```

Comment: What do you mean with *behind*? Is your object facing a certain direction? Do you mean your camera is pointing away from the mesh? Please clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Often it looks better for it to be located up a little also, for example:

```
cameraPosition = objectPosition +
                 object.Backward * 10 +
                 object.Up * 5;

cameraTarget = objectPosition +
               object.Up * 3;
```

This places the camera behind and above the object. And has it kind of looking past the object which is good for a camera following a car.

The sky is the limit on adjustments here, you can even use input to modify it some.

Comment: Yes I did this, but thats the problem, the camera always behind the object, I dont wnat to, I just want it to be some units away, and stay at this position, I mean the camera should stay for example 10 units away, and dont cahnge position when the object rotates

Comment: I see. Then create an offset vector from the object to the camera at the very start. Then, every frame, set the camera position to the objectPosition + offset; As long as you never alter the offset, the camera will move with the object but not be subject to the orientation of the object.

Comment: And how can I make the camera be behind the object but only after few moments, I mean, yo rotated the object and now the camera move slowly until it will be behind the object?